# Infinite vertical scrollView with loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, infinite-scroll

Are there any examples of infinite vertical scrollview, something like Facebook and 9gag app. When you scroll it shows for example pictures, but it stops after lets say 10 pictures showing refresh/loading indicator, and then loading new pictures (so it doesn't have to download all pics at app start).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This [amazing dev](http://samvermette.com/) has made it easy to add infinite scroll with a `UIScrollView` [category](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh). You should probably give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

when user scroll upside then it call the following method

```
 #pragma mark -
 #pragma mark - Scroll View Delegate Method

    - (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
       if (scrollView == scrollObj) {
            CGFloat scrollPosition = scrollObj.contentSize.height - scrollObj.frame.size.height - scrollObj.contentOffset.y;
            if (scrollPosition < 30)
            {
                if ((!spinnerBottom.isAnimating) ) {
                    [spinnerBottom startAnimating];
                    [self getAPICall]; //your apicall function 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```